# Write the set $\{1, 6, 11, 16,\ldots\}$ in compact (concise) notation.

Tags: number-theory

I got the answer as the set $\{5x + 1 : x \in \mathbb{N} ∪ \{0\} \}$. Can anyone confirm if this is correct? Thanks.

Comment: What does "writing as a compact set" mean?  Either it's a compact set or not.  And that won't change no matter how you right it.  (Under the Euclidean metric it clearly isn't compact because you can take an open cover of small disjoint intervals each containing exactly one of the infinite terms of the set.)

Comment: We say "set builder" notation, not "compact."

Comment: For set notation that is good.  You can also do $\{5x -4: x \in \mathbb N\}$ or $\{5x + 1| x\ge 0; x \in \mathbb Z\}$ etc.